# World gas/petrol prices at the pump

Tags: data-request, prices

Is anyone aware of a source for data related to the world gas/petrol prices at the pump?  The websites I've seen are all either selling data or just dealing with the global market price.  I'm interested in the actual sale price per litre/gallon at the pump.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best guess is [World petrol prices](http://www.mytravelcost.com/petrol-prices/) on MyTravelCost.com. They give you a large, configurable bar chart of gasoline prices. However, their source description can be described *vague* at best:

> The data are drawn from a variety of sources including official government materials, oil companies, online resources specializing in gas prices, and others. These sources provide reliable information about fuel prices in a large number of countries. For the other countries, we provide an estimate using previously published data.

**Bonus:** If you want to access the raw data, simply right-click on the graphic an open the (incredibly long) image URL in a new tab. It contains the raw data for the bar chart like this:

```
http://www.mytravelcost.com/graph.php
?data=0.02,0.09,0.15,0.18,...
&titles=0.02|0.09|0.15|0.18|...
&outsideGraphTitles=Venezuela|Iran|Saudi%20Arabia|Qatar|...
```

Comment: Well done for spotting the URL contains the data.

Answer (score 4):

The data you're looking for is available here -:

https://www.datazar.com/project/pe1c88ca8-57a8-48b8-89a6-89083da7fc3c

It has historical data from 1918, it is free and open for use.

P.S- I work for datazar, an open source data library, where this file is hosted.

Comment: Price at the pump? Which pump would this be?

Answer (score 3):

Another source of this data, just discovered - from the World Bank:
 - [petrol/gas](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EP.PMP.SGAS.CD)
 - [diesel](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EP.PMP.DESL.CD)