# API for crowd sourced gas prices

Tags: api, crowdsourcing

Does anyone have a source for current daily gas prices at any given pump? IE the Kirkland Costco is selling regular unleaded for 2.89 on 10/15/2015.

The data I am looking for is at gasbuddy.com but they charge and I am looking for current, and not historical, prices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [World gas/petrol prices at the pump](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/world-gas-petrol-prices-at-the-pump)

Comment: If you take a look at [gasbuddy.com](http://www.gasbuddy.com), you will see the level of detail I am looking for. I would like to see an open source for each specific address/station.